Best resources for Solana Beginners in 2024
I am a beginner in this area.I would like to now the best resources for solana.

This question is similar to: How to Learn Solana Blockchain as a MERN stack developer. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Previously answered here https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/14880/1708
If you are just getting stared

learn about blockchain fundamentals https://solana.com/learn/blockchain-basics
set up your Solana environment https://solana.com/developers/guides/getstarted/setup-local-development

If you prefer written tutorials check these out

https://www.rareskills.io/solana-tutorial

https://www.soldev.app/course

https://learn.calyptus.co/learn-solana/

https://www.risein.com/courses/build-on-solana


Also check out the developer guides on the Solana docs website. You can filter based on your experience and search for specific topics

https://solana.com/developers/guides

If you are a visual learner, Nick from the Developer Relations also has a wonderful course on the same https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLilwLeBwGuK6NsYMPP_BlVkeQgff0NwvU
Freecodecamp also have a Solana tutorial https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/solana-curriculum/
